# How to access Express request in validate function of Passport JWT in Nestjs?

Tags: nestjs, passport.js

I can't access request from Express in validate function. It returns the payload instead:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PrismaService } from 'src/prisma/prisma.service';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt') {
  constructor(config: ConfigService, private prisma: PrismaService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors([
        (request: Request) => {
          //Check if user has cookie "access_token"
          if (
            request.cookies &&
            'access_token' in request.cookies &&
            request.cookies.access_token.length > 0
          ) {
            return request.cookies.access_token;
          }
          return null;
        },
      ]),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: config.get('JWT_SECRET'),
    });
  }

  async validate(request: Request, payload: any) {
    console.log(request);
    console.log(payload)
  }
}
```

Request argument returns the payload and payload argument returns [Fucntion]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the request to show up in `validate` you have to add `passReqToCallback: true` to the option you supply to `super` in the `constructor` of your `JwtStrategy`. Without it, the parameters of `validate` are the parsed JWT and the callback function for `verify`